# How to change the plot range of on an axis other than z in a ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting

```
ListPlot3D[Table[Tan[j i], {i, 0, Pi, 0.1}, {j, 0, Pi, 0.1}]]
```

[image: Mathematica generated plot]

I want to choose the plot range of y or x-axis so that for example only the right "hill" of the graph is shown. The code is just for illustration purposes. My actual plot uses a huge set of data points that take a few minutes to generate a full plot.

I tried searching the *Mathematica* documentation and this site, but so far no luck. I know the usage of:

`DataRange` >> it only change the value of axis label (or tick), but not choosing plot range

`PlotRange` >> it chooses z-axis range, but I want to choose x and y-axis too.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: You must have missed it in the documentation: `PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}, {zmin, zmax}}`.

Answer (score 4):

With your code, I do not obtain your plot.  Instead,

[image]

In any case, `PlotRange` can take arguments for all three dimensions, as can be seen from its [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html); see "Details".

```
ListPlot3D[Table[Tan[j i], {i, 0, Pi, 0.1}, {j, 0, Pi, 0.1}], 
 PlotRange -> {{16, 32}, {16, 32}, {-5, 5}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative. Because my data is array of values.

Example:

```
data = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 
1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 
1}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1}};
```

and each value correspond to the value in z-axis. Using part ([[...]]) can do the trick as well.

```
ListPlot3D[data[[1 ;; 5, 3 ;; 6]]]
```